# Choice Experiment - Trouble with WTP Calculation in R

Tags: r, mlogit, gmnl

I'm currently working on a research project and facing some challenges with WTP (Willingness to Pay) calculation using R. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights you could provide.
I recently conducted a choice experiment to explore preferences for a product featuring various attributes associated with sustainable production. I need to calculate WTP for each of these attributes.

**Data Structure:**
The current structure of my raw data is as follows:

```
| ID    | chosen | ecosust | socialsust | general_sust | price |
|-------|--------|---------|------------|--------------|-------|
| 174   | WAHR   | none    | none       | gensus        | 8.99  |
| 174   | WAHR   | none    | fair       | none          | 8.99  |
| 174   | WAHR   | water   | fair       | none          | 12.99 |
| 174   | FALSCH | energy  | fair       | none          | 12.99 |
| 174   | FALSCH | energy  | gender     | none          | 12.99 |
| 174   | FALSCH | energy  | fair       | none          | 8.99  |
| 174   | FALSCH | water   | none       | none          | 4.99  |
| 174   | FALSCH | none    | gender     | none          | 8.99  |
| 174   | FALSCH | water   | gender     | none          | 12.99 |
| 177   | WAHR   | energy  | gender     | none          | 8.99  |
| 177   | WAHR   | none    | none       | gensus        | 4.99  |
| 177   | WAHR   | water   | fair       | none          | 12.99 |
| 177   | FALSCH | none    | none       | gensus        | 4.99  |
| 177   | FALSCH | energy  | gender     | none          | 8.99  |
```

**First approach:**
I created a model using the following function:

```
model <- db %>%     
mutate(     indv = "Interview-Nummer (fortlaufend)"   ) %>%    
glmer(chosen ~ general_sust + ecosust + socialsust + price + (1|indv) + (1|choice), data = ., family = binomial)
```

I attempted to calculate WTP using the line:

```
wtp.gmnl(model, wrt = c("general_sust", "ecosust", "socialsust", "price")
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
Error in if (i != posi) { : the condition has length > 1
```

**Alternative Approach with logitr Package:**

my second approach was using the logitr package to create the model and then calculate the WTP from there.
however, i kept getting errors when creating the model.

```
logitr(   data    = db,   outcome = "chosen",   obsID   = "Interview-Nummer (fortlaufend)",   pars    = c("price", "ecosust", "socialsust", "general_sust") )
```

here, i get this error:

```
Error in checkRepeatedIDs("obsID", obsID, reps) :    The 'obsID' variable provided has repeated ID values.
```

this confuses me, since in a paper concering this package, the variable obsID is defined as:

> *"A sequence of repeated numbers that identifies each unique choice
> observation. For example, if the first three choice observations had 2 alternatives each,
> then the first 6 rows of the obsID variable would be 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3."*

I suspect the issue might be related to the structure of my data, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In `mutate(     indv = "Interview-Nummer (fortlaufend)"   )` you create one column named `indv` and assign the *value* `"Interview-Nummer (fortlaufend)"` to the entire column. This seems wrong.